# find the integer points in a polyhedron

Tags: geometry, linear-programming, enumerate, feasibility

Hello we have a polyhedron with the linear inequalities of its boundaries in n dimensions.

1. how to find the number of integer points in this polyhedron (exactly or approximately).
2. how to find the coordinates of the integer points in this polyhedron.

Comment: This algorithm is very parallelizable if your *n* is not too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you some search terms: what you describe is an *enumeration* of *feasible solutions* to an *integer program.*

Last time I needed something like this, I couldn't find a ready-to-use solution, so I wrote my own implementation called “[bande](http://martin.von-gagern.net/projects/idp/)”. It is based on a branching algorithm, using the linear programming engine from [COIN-OR](http://www.coin-or.org/) to decide whether the corresponding linear (non-integer) program has any feasible solutions. Feel free to use that it it suits your need.

As to simply determining the *number* of lattice points: I believe there was some formula to compute that, but I don't remember any details. As far as I remember, that formula was no use in actually enumerating the solutions.

Looking at [recent publications](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jsc.2003.04.003) suggests that you might want to have a look at [LattE](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/).

Answer (score 0):

Software beeing able to compute the integer points of a given polyhedron (among the convex hull) is [porta](http://typo.zib.de/opt-long_projects/Software/Porta/%20Porta).

However, all software concerning this problem base on enumerations, such that it fails for larger models.

Best regards